# Send ArrayList over the network - Convert Java ArrayList to XML String

Tags: java, silverlight, xml-serialization

I'm new to Java. I want to send an array (ArrayList) of objects over the network via Java Web Service to my Silverlight app. This ArrayList contains custom class objects:

```
ArrayList<SVNSearchResult> results
```

so I'm thinking the best way is to serialize this to an XML String and on the Silverlight part, use LinQ to parse it. If there's a better way to send it please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is a good fit for this. JSON would be one of the other usual suspects these days.

Whatever format you end up choosing, make sure you get the encoding right.

Comment: So how can I use these? Could you please post a code snippet or tutorial? Performance is very crucial. Thanks.

Comment: That's a different question - you asked whether your option was good. It is, there are others like `JSON` that are popular. If you have trouble implementing this, post another question with what you have so far and the _specific_ problems you're not managing to solve. Don't forget to search the internet for "java xml", "java json", and the same for Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks. I found XStream. I think I'm gonna go with that. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: After trying to use it, I didn't want to use a 3rd party library so I created my own class with the help of DOM.

Answer (score 3):

For a starter, try [JSON](http://json.org). It has a network-efficient format, and is supported by any major language in the world.

XML is only my second choice as it is more complicated to generate/parse and is more verbose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm going to use XML. Parsing it with the use of LinQ is no biggie and I'm familiar with it.